# Assignment inside lambda expression in Python

Tags: python, lambda, expression, variable-assignment

I have a list of objects and I want to remove all objects that are empty except for one, using `filter` and a `lambda` expression.

For example if the input is:

```
[Object(name=""), Object(name="fake_name"), Object(name="")]
```

...then the output should be:

```
[Object(name=""), Object(name="fake_name")]
```

Is there a way to add an assignment to a `lambda` expression? For example:

```
flag = True 
input = [Object(name=""), Object(name="fake_name"), Object(name="")] 
output = filter(
    (lambda o: [flag or bool(o.name), flag = flag and bool(o.name)][0]),
    input
)
```

Comment: Why not just pass a regular old function into filter?

Comment: I wanted to use lambda just so it would be a really compact solution. I remember in OCaml I could chain print statements before the return expression, thought this could be replicated in Python

Comment: It is quite painful to be in the flow of developing a chained pipeilne then realize: "oh I want to create a temp var to make the flow more clear" or "i want to log this intermediate step" : and then you have to jump somewhere else to create a function to do it: and _name_ that function and keep track of it - even though it's used in just one place .

Comment: See also [Assignment inside lambda expression in Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282042/assignment-inside-lambda-expression-in-python) for the special case (++ or -- operator in C)

Answer (score 277):

[The assignment expression operator `:=` added in Python 3.8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) supports assignment inside of lambda expressions. This operator can only appear within a parenthesized `(...)`, bracketed `[...]`, or braced `{...}` expression for syntactic reasons. For example, we will be able to write the following:

```python
import sys
say_hello = lambda: (
    message := "Hello world",
    sys.stdout.write(message + "\n")
)[-1]
say_hello()
```

In Python 2, it was possible to perform local assignments as a side effect of list comprehensions.

```python
import sys
say_hello = lambda: (
    [None for message in ["Hello world"]],
    sys.stdout.write(message + "\n")
)[-1]
say_hello()
```

However, it's not possible to use either of these in your example because your variable `flag` is in an outer scope, not the `lambda`'s scope. This doesn't have to do with `lambda`, it's the general behaviour in Python 2. Python 3 lets you get around this with the `nonlocal` keyword inside of `def`s, but `nonlocal` can't be used inside `lambda`s.

There's a workaround (see below), but while we're on the topic...

---

In some cases you can use this to do everything inside of a `lambda`:

```python
(lambda: [
    ['def'
        for sys in [__import__('sys')]
        for math in [__import__('math')]

        for sub in [lambda *vals: None]
        for fun in [lambda *vals: vals[-1]]

        for echo in [lambda *vals: sub(
            sys.stdout.write(u" ".join(map(unicode, vals)) + u"\n"))]

        for Cylinder in [type('Cylinder', (object,), dict(
            __init__ = lambda self, radius, height: sub(
                setattr(self, 'radius', radius),
                setattr(self, 'height', height)),

            volume = property(lambda self: fun(
                ['def' for top_area in [math.pi * self.radius ** 2]],

                self.height * top_area))))]

        for main in [lambda: sub(
            ['loop' for factor in [1, 2, 3] if sub(
                ['def'
                    for my_radius, my_height in [[10 * factor, 20 * factor]]
                    for my_cylinder in [Cylinder(my_radius, my_height)]],

                echo(u"A cylinder with a radius of %.1fcm and a height "
                     u"of %.1fcm has a volume of %.1fcm³."
                     % (my_radius, my_height, my_cylinder.volume)))])]],

    main()])()
```

> A cylinder with a radius of 10.0cm and a height of 20.0cm has a volume of 6283.2cm³.
>   A cylinder with a radius of 20.0cm and a height of 40.0cm has a volume of 50265.5cm³.
>   A cylinder with a radius of 30.0cm and a height of 60.0cm has a volume of 169646.0cm³.

Please don't.

---

...back to your original example: though you can't perform assignments to the `flag` variable in the outer scope, you can use functions to modify the previously-assigned value.

For example, `flag` could be an object whose `.value` we set  using [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```python
flag = Object(value=True)
input = [Object(name=''), Object(name='fake_name'), Object(name='')] 
output = filter(lambda o: [
    flag.value or bool(o.name),
    setattr(flag, 'value', flag.value and bool(o.name))
][0], input)
```

```
[Object(name=''), Object(name='fake_name')]
```

If we wanted to fit the above theme, we could use a list comprehension instead of `setattr`:

```python
    [None for flag.value in [bool(o.name)]]
```

---

But really, in serious code you should always use a regular function definition instead of a `lambda` if you're going to be doing outer assignment.

```python
flag = Object(value=True)
def not_empty_except_first(o):
    result = flag.value or bool(o.name)
    flag.value = flag.value and bool(o.name)
    return result
input = [Object(name=""), Object(name="fake_name"), Object(name="")] 
output = filter(not_empty_except_first, input)
```

Comment: The last example in this answer doesn't produce the same output as the example, but it looks to me like the example output is incorrect.

Comment: in short, this boils down to: use `.setattr()` and alikes (_dictionaries_ should do as well, for instance) to hack side effects into functional code   
   
  anyway, cool code by @JeremyBanks was shown :)

Answer (score 41):

You cannot really maintain state in a `filter`/`lambda` expression (unless abusing the global namespace). You can however achieve something similar using the accumulated result being passed around in a `reduce()` expression:

```
>>> f = lambda a, b: (a.append(b) or a) if (b not in a) else a
>>> input = ["foo", u"", "bar", "", "", "x"]
>>> reduce(f, input, [])
['foo', u'', 'bar', 'x']
>>>
```

You can, of course, tweak the condition a bit. In this case it filters out duplicates, but you can also use `a.count("")`, for example, to only restrict empty strings.

Needless to say, you can do this but you really shouldn't. :)

Lastly, you *can* do anything in pure Python `lambda`: http://vanderwijk.info/blog/pure-lambda-calculus-python/

Answer (score 21):

Normal assignment (`=`) is not possible inside a `lambda` expression, although it is possible to perform various tricks with `setattr` and friends.

Solving your problem, however, is actually quite simple:

```
input = [Object(name=""), Object(name="fake_name"), Object(name="")]
output = filter(
    lambda o, _seen=set():
        not (not o and o in _seen or _seen.add(o)),
    input
    )
```

which will give you

```
[Object(Object(name=''), name='fake_name')]
```

As you can see, it's keeping the first blank instance instead of the last.  If you need the last instead, reverse the list going in to `filter`, and reverse the list coming out of `filter`:

```
output = filter(
    lambda o, _seen=set():
        not (not o and o in _seen or _seen.add(o)),
    input[::-1]
    )[::-1]
```

which will give you

```
[Object(name='fake_name'), Object(name='')]
```

One thing to be aware of: in order for this to work with arbitrary objects, those objects must properly implement `__eq__` and `__hash__` as explained [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=hash#object.__hash__).

Answer (score 18):

There's no need to use a lambda, when you can remove *all* the null ones, and put one back if the input size changes:

```
input = [Object(name=""), Object(name="fake_name"), Object(name="")] 
output = [x for x in input if x.name]
if(len(input) != len(output)):
    output.append(Object(name=""))
```

Comment: I think you have a small mistake in your code. The second line should be `output = [x for x in input if x.name]`.

Comment: Order of elements may be important.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**:

```
[o for d in [{}] for o in lst if o.name != "" or d.setdefault("", o) == o]
```

or using `filter` and `lambda`:

```
flag = {}
filter(lambda o: bool(o.name) or flag.setdefault("", o) == o, lst)
```

*Previous Answer*

OK, are you stuck on using filter and lambda?

It seems like this would be better served with a dictionary comprehension,

```
{o.name : o for o in input}.values()
```

I think the reason that Python doesn't allow assignment in a lambda is similar to why it doesn't allow assignment in a comprehension and that's got something to do with the fact that these things are evaluated on the `C` side and thus can give us an increase in speed. At least that's my impression after reading [one of Guido's essays](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/).

My guess is this would also go against the philosophy of having *one* right way of doing any one thing in Python.

Comment: So this isn't completely right. It won't preserve order, nor will it preserve duplicates of non-empty-stringed objects.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR: When using functional idioms it's better to write functional code**

As many people have pointed out, in Python lambdas assignment is not allowed.  In general when using functional idioms your better off thinking in a functional manner which means wherever possible no side effects and no assignments.

Here is functional solution which uses a lambda.  I've assigned the lambda to `fn` for clarity (and because it got a little long-ish).

```
from operator import add
from itertools import ifilter, ifilterfalse
fn = lambda l, pred: add(list(ifilter(pred, iter(l))), [ifilterfalse(pred, iter(l)).next()])
objs = [Object(name=""), Object(name="fake_name"), Object(name="")]
fn(objs, lambda o: o.name != '')
```

You can also make this deal with iterators rather than lists by changing things around a little.  You also have some different imports.

```
from itertools import chain, islice, ifilter, ifilterfalse
fn = lambda l, pred: chain(ifilter(pred, iter(l)), islice(ifilterfalse(pred, iter(l)), 1))
```

You can always reoganize the code to reduce the length of the statements.

Answer (score 8):

The pythonic way to track state during iteration is with generators. The itertools way is quite hard to understand IMHO and trying to hack lambdas to do this is plain silly. I'd try:

```
def keep_last_empty(input):
    last = None
    for item in iter(input):
        if item.name: yield item
        else: last = item
    if last is not None: yield last

output = list(keep_last_empty(input))
```

Overall, readability trumps compactness every time.

Answer (score 7):

If instead of `flag = True` we can do an import instead, then I think this meets the criteria:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> a = ['hello', '', 'world', '', '', '', 'bob']
>>> filter(lambda L, j=count(): L or not next(j), a)
['hello', '', 'world', 'bob']
```

Or maybe the filter is better written as:

```
>>> filter(lambda L, blank_count=count(1): L or next(blank_count) == 1, a)
```

Or, just for a simple boolean, without any imports:

```
filter(lambda L, use_blank=iter([True]): L or next(use_blank, False), a)
```

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot put an assignment inside a lambda because of its own definition. If you work using functional programming, then you must assume that your values are not mutable.

One solution would be the following code:

```
output = lambda l, name: [] if l==[] \
             else [ l[ 0 ] ] + output( l[1:], name ) if l[ 0 ].name == name \
             else output( l[1:], name ) if l[ 0 ].name == "" \
             else [ l[ 0 ] ] + output( l[1:], name )
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need a lambda to remember state between calls, I would recommend either a function declared in the local namespace or a class with an overloaded `__call__`. Now that all my cautions against what you are trying to do is out of the way, we can get to an actual answer to your query.

If you really need to have your lambda to have some memory between calls, you can define it like:

```
f = lambda o, ns = {"flag":True}: [ns["flag"] or o.name, ns.__setitem__("flag", ns["flag"] and o.name)][0]
```

Then you just need to pass `f` to `filter()`. If you really need to, you can get back the value of `flag` with the following:

```
f.__defaults__[0]["flag"]
```

Alternatively, you can modify the global namespace by modifying the result of `globals()`. Unfortunately, you cannot modify the local namespace in the same way as modifying the result of `locals()` doesn't affect the local namespace.

Comment: Or just use the original Lisp:  `(let ((var 42)) (lambda () (setf var 43)))`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a bind function to use a pseudo multi-statement lambda.  Then you can use a wrapper class for a Flag to enable assignment.

```
bind = lambda x, f=(lambda y: y): f(x)

class Flag(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def set(self, value):
        self.value = value
        return value

input = [Object(name=""), Object(name="fake_name"), Object(name="")]
flag = Flag(True)
output = filter(
            lambda o: (
                bind(flag.value, lambda orig_flag_value:
                bind(flag.set(flag.value and bool(o.name)), lambda _:
                bind(orig_flag_value or bool(o.name))))),
            input)
```

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a messy workaround, but assignment in lambdas is illegal anyway, so it doesn't really matter. You can use the builtin `exec()` function to run assignment from inside the lambda, such as this example:

```py
>>> val
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 1, in <module>
    val
NameError: name 'val' is not defined
>>> d = lambda: exec('val=True', globals())
>>> d()
>>> val
True
```

Answer (score -2):

first , you dont need to use a local assigment for your job, just check the above answer

second, its simple to use locals() and globals() to got the variables table and then change the value

check this sample code:

```
print [locals().__setitem__('x', 'Hillo :]'), x][-1]
```

if you need to change the add a global variable to your environ, try to replace **locals()** with **globals()**

python's list comp is cool but most of the triditional project dont accept this(like flask :[)

hope it could help

Comment: You cannot use `locals()`, it explicitly says in the documentation that changing it doesn't actually change the local scope (or at least it won't always). `globals()` on the other hand works as expected.

Comment: @JPvdMerwe just try it, dont follow the document blindly. and assignment in lambda is **breaking rule** already

Comment: It unfortunately only works in the global namespace, in which case you really should be using `globals()`. http://pastebin.com/5Bjz1mR4 (tested in both 2.6 and 3.2) proves it.