# Set attribute in callback, with lambda

Tags: python, lambda, callback

Trying to figure out how to set a object attribute using a lambda function.

i got a case where i need to set the attribute with a UI callBack, that requires a function object.

was trying something like this but it dosnt work, and gives me a syntax error.

```
pm.button(command=lambda *args: uvOpts.grid = True)
```

Comment: I think value assignment of a variable inside lambda scope is not possible. Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282042/assignment-inside-lambda-expression-in-python

Answer (score 3):

this solves the syntax error (you cannot have a second "`=`" in `pm.button`) and works if `uvOpts` is in the [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules?lq=1).

```
pm.button(command=lambda *args: setattr(uvOpts, 'grid', True))
```

to set the object's attribute I'm using [setattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr), in order to avoid the use of a `=` symbol in `lambda` function definition.

---

I would like to add that if you need to make `uvOpts` visible inside the lambda scope you may **eventually** need to make it *global*, at least at *module level* (e.g. read the answers in [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)).

Comment: `*args` isn't needed, so a simple `pm.button(command=lambda: setattr(uvOpts, 'grid', True))` would suffice.

Comment: @martineau You are right, but since I don't know if `args` may be needed for any other reason (the OP may have just simplified his/her question), and in order to let cmcPasserby to identify the minimum change needed to solve the error I kept it. If unneeded, the arguments may be removed. Thanks for highlighting this aspect!

Comment: I would suggest answering questions based solely on their content rather than second-guessing what details the OP might be leaving out.

Comment: @martineau I prefer to keep it because I do not want to let the "distract reader" to think that `*args` is part of the problem. It's just unneeded in the context, but it does not cause harm as well. I should have mentioned in my answer that the argument is unnecessary, you are right, but now there is your comment to state this additional aspect (and this is why I voted up your comment) :).