# Lambda expressions in Python

Tags: python

Can lambda expression has multiple lines in Python? Like common functions.

Can I do something like that?

```
res = lambda x y:
    z = x**2 + 5
    z + x + y
```

(I know that this function can be written on one line, It's an example)

Comment: No, they can't; just use a regular `def`.

Comment: The main purpose of `lambda` function is that it can be define in-line. If you want to use a multi line function you can simply use regular functions with `def`.

Comment: The key word here is lambda *expression*; it cannot contain any statement, let alone more than one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be split across multiple *lines* by the same rule that any expression can be split across multiple lines. You can use backslash `\` to prevent a linebreak ending the current statement, or use the fact that linebreaks are permitted within the various forms of brackets: `()`, `[]`, `{}`.

However, a lambda expression is just that, an expression. It cannot contain assignment statements (or any other statements).

The precise details are defined by [the Python grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO , you can't.

If you need some temporary variable in a lambda function, as a ugly workaround you can do :

```
res = lambda x,y : [ z**2 + z**4 + z  for z in [x**2+5]][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

For an interesting example of how far you can take lambda expressions check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282042/assignment-inside-lambda-expression-in-python) out.

Although you should absolutely use a function for this.

Comment: This outputs to standard output and returns `[None]`.