# Can you assign variables in a lambda?

Tags: python, variables, lambda

I was using a `lambda` statement to perform math, and happened to repeatedly use one certain value. Therefore I was wondering if it was possible to assign and use a variable within a `lambda` statement.

I have tried things like:

```
a = lambda n:(b=3+2*n) #[my math here]
```

However this just raises errors, and I was wondering if there was a way to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282042/assignment-inside-lambda-expression-in-python

Comment: I don't think this really is a duplicate of that question. While the title is very similar, the actual problem seems to be a bit different. (Actually just wanted to vote for re-open, forgot about anti-dupe-hammer...)

Comment: You can assign variable in lambda using walrus operator (in Python 3.8).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nope, you can't. Only expressions allowed in [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

> ```
> lambda_expr        ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list]: expression
> lambda_expr_nocond ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list]: expression_nocond
> ```

You could, however, define a *second* `lambda` *inside* the `lambda` and immediately call it with the parameter you want. (Whether that's really better might be another question.)

```
>>> a = lambda n: ((3+2*n), n*(3+2*n))  # for reference, with repetition
>>> a(42)
(87, 3654)
>>> a2 = lambda n: (lambda b: (b, n*b))(3+2*n)  # lambda inside lambda
>>> a2(42)
(87, 3654)
>>> a3 = lambda n: (lambda b=3+2*n: (b, n*b))()  # using default parameter
>>> a3(42)
(87, 3654)
```

Of course, both the outer and the inner lambda can have more than one parameter, i.e. you can define multiple "variables" at once. The benefit of this approach over, e.g., defining a second lambda *outside* of the first is, that you can still also use the original parameters (not possible if you invoked `a` with `b` pre-calculated) and you have to do the calculation for `b` only once (other than repeatedly invoking a function for the calculation of `b` within `a`).

---

Also, inspired by the [top answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14617232/1639625), you could also define one or more variables as part of a list comprehension or generator within the lambda, and then get the `next` (first and only) result from that generator or list:

```
>>> a4 = lambda n: next((b, n*b) for b in [3+2*n])
>>> a4(42)
(87, 3654)
```

However, I think the intent behind the lambda-in-a-lambda is a bit clearer. Finally, keep in mind that instead of a one-line `lambda`, you could also just use a much clearer three-line `def` statement...

---

Also, starting with Python 3.8, there will be [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), which *should* make it possible to write something like this. (Tested with Python 3.8.10.)

```
>>> a5 = lambda n: ((b := 3+2*n), n*b)
```

Comment: To newer visitors: note that the last proposition does not work with Python 3.8 as assignment expressions are disallowed in lambda functions.

Comment: @AdrienW It doesn't  work because he forgot a parenthesis: `a5 = (lambda n: ((b := 3+2*n), n*b))`. Other than that, assignment expressions work perfectly fine with lambdas.

Comment: @AdrienW but you are right too, because of the parenthesis , it is not used directly with lambda, but within a tuple, or when parenthesizing as operator , with whatever object it evaluates too.

Comment: @Spartan Thanks for pointing out, fixed the parens. (Not sure what you mean with your 2nd comment, though.)

Comment: @tobias_k try something like `lambda x: x:=1` and you will understand :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just pass your lambda an argument which passes it along to another argument if you wish:

```
>>> b = lambda x: 3 + 2*x
>>> a = lambda y: y * b(y)
>>> a(1)
5
>>> a(2)
14
```

Comment: No what I was trying to do is use the argument passed to the lambda to do calculations, but I repeatedly performed the operation `3+2*n` to the argument so I wanted to assign that to a variable.

Answer (score 3):

Im no expert at this, but the way i did it was by modifying `globals()` or `locals()`
like this:

```
lambda: globals().__setitem__('some_variable', 'some value')
```

or if it's inside a function:

```
lambda: locals().__setitem__('some_variable', 'some value')
```

you could also use `update()` instead of `__setitem__()` if you wanted to, but that's a bit redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You can create 2 different lambda functions and pass one to the other. For example,

```
b = lambda x: 3+2*x
a = lambda y: [my math here using variable b(y)]
```

Comment: this is bad and considered as an anti pattern : https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/assigning_a_lambda_to_a_variable.html

Answer (score 2):

I've cooked up this recipe for python 3.8+ using PEP572 Assignment Expressions to assign arbitrary variables and execute arbitrary expressions.

```py
# python 3.8b1
lambda a: (
    (bool(b:=a**2) or 1)
    and (bool(c:=a-b) or 1)
    and not print(f'compute: {a} + {b} + {c}')
    and (
        (ret:=a + b + c) or ret)
    )
)
tst(0) 
# prints: "compute: 0 + 0 + 0"; returns: 0
tst(1)
# prints: "compute: 1 + 1 + 0"; returns: 2
tst(8)
# prints: "compute: 8 + 64 + -56"; returns: 16
```

So the pattern is:

```py
lambda: [*vars]: (
    (bool(a:=[expr(*vars)]) or 1)
    and (bool([expr]) or 1)
    and bool([always true expr])
    and not bool([always false expr])
    and (
        # parentheses required so `result:=` doesn't capture the `or result` part
        (result:=[result expr]) or result
    )
)
```

This may be simplified if you know the truthiness of any particular expression.

That being said, if you want to assign a variable to reuse inside a lambda, you probably should consider writing a normal function.

Answer (score 1):

*i hope that after 4 years my late answer will be useful*

Python has `setattr` function to set attribute of given object. You can use it in your lambda expression.

`setattr` is useful when you want to programmatically-correctly *(sorry)* set some class or class' instance. It is not used frequently because it is easier to assign variables directly with `=` expression. But for lambdas... It is a salvation.

Also, iterables that support settign item (such as list), you can use `<iter>.__setitem__`.

#### **Option 1**. If you know the name of variable you're assigning.

```
x = lambda nameofvar, value: setattr(__builtins__, nameofvar, value)

# abc does not exist right now. Assigning and setting it to 10
x('abc', 10)
print(abc) # output: 10
```

**alt**, if you want to set object's attribute:

```
class MyClass:
    my_attr = False
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
myinstance = MyClass(25)

x = lambda obj, nameofvar, value: setattr(obj, nameofvar, value)
short_x = lambda nameofvar, value: setattr(MyClass, nameofvar, value)
# ^^^ this one works only for MyClass' attributes.

print(MyClass.my_attr) # output: False
x(MyClass, 'my_attr', True) # Changing MyClass' my_attr's value
print(MyClass.my_attr) # output: True
x(MyClass, 'my_attr2', 5) # Assigning new attribute to MyClass
print(MyClass.my_attr2) # output: 5
short_x('my_attr2', 123) # Setting MyClass' my_attr2 to 123
print(MyClass.my_attr2) # output: 123

print(myinstance.value) # output: 25
x(myinstance, 'value', 500)
print(myinstance.value) # output: 500
```

#### **Option 2**. Make a custom class and turn variable into its instance.

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

x = lambda var, newvalue: setattr(var, 'value', newvalue)

a = Value(15)
print(a.value) # output: 15
x(a, 25)
print(a.value) # output: 25
```

#### **Option 3**. To set object's item.

```
lst = [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90]

x = lambda iterable, item, value: iterable.__setitem__(item, value)

print(lst) # output: [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90]
x(lst, 2, 1000)
print(lst) # output: [15, 30, 1000, 60, 75, 90]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use a bit of creativity, for example if you want to do some evaluation to an equation and assign the result to a variable it can be done like this:

```
class Results:
    res = 0

clas= Results()
setattr(clas, 'res', 3+2*4)
print(clas.res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite this in a oop way, like this, maybe you are using an oop structure anyways so you could integrate it in there.

```
class example:
     def __init__(self):
         self.a = None

 object = example()
 a = lambda n:(setattr(object, "a", 3+2*n)) #[my math here]
 a(2)
 print(object.a)
```

Output:

> 7