# Python 3.8+, assignment in lambda function

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, python-3.8

I have following function:

```
sorted(
    [
        #...
    ],
    key=lambda x: (
        x.get("order", {}).get("data") is None,
        x.get("order", {}).get("data"),
    ),
)
```

Can I use assignment `:=` here to store `x.get("order", {}).get("data")` in variable?

Comment: Use a list comprehension before you give it to sorted

Comment: Sure you can. How does it not work for you?

Comment: `:=` should work; but there are also [some ugly alternatives for older versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45337189/1639625)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, just make sure to paranthesize the expression correctly:

```
sorted(
    [
        #...
    ],
    key=lambda x: (
        (y := x.get("order", {}).get("data")) is None,
        y,
    ),
)
```