# a strange usage for lambda in python

Tags: python, lambda

I encounter a part of code as follows, where `workers` is a list of class object:

```
worker_threads = []
for worker in workers:
    worker_fn = lambda worker=worker: worker.run(sess, coord, FLAGS.t_max)
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker_fn)
    t.start()
    worker_threads.append(t)
```

Normally I expect the syntax for `lambda` is `lambda x : func(x)`, but in here what is the `worker=worker` used for ?

Comment: Does it work or does it cause error?

Comment: I believe that is working just like any other param would in a function, it is setting the for loop `worker` as the default value of the lambda expression

Comment: [variable assignment is not allowed inside lambda expression.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337189/can-you-assign-variables-in-a-lambda)

Comment: It's binding the value of `worker` within the lambda to its value as of when the lambda was executed.  If you don't do that, the value of `worker` will change within all the lambdas as the `for` loop iterates.

Comment: Lemme see if I can come up with a minimum example of this as an actual answer...

Comment: It might be working, but in the context of Zen - it’s unPythonic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's being done to bind the value of `worker` inside the lambda.  Here's a simplified example of this technique:

```
>>> thunks = [lambda: i for i in range(5)]
>>> [thunk() for thunk in thunks]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
>>>
>>> thunks = [lambda i=i: i for i in range(5)]
>>> [thunk() for thunk in thunks]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

With the expression `lambda: i`, `i` is evaluated at the time the lambda is *called*, not when it is *defined*.  Hence in the first example, the results from all of the thunks are `4` because that's the value that `i` has at the end of the `range(5)` loop.

With the expression `lambda i=i: i`, now the value of `i` is being evaluated immediately within the loop in order to provide the default value of the `i` parameter.  This allows each thunk to capture a unique value of `i`.

The concept might be more clear if the parameter is given a different name instead of shadowing `i`:

```
>>> thunks = [lambda n=i: n for i in range(5)]
>>> [thunk() for thunk in thunks]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In your example, the lambda could be written as:

```
worker_fn = lambda w=worker: w.run(sess, coord, FLAGS.t_max)
```

This behaves the same as the `worker=worker: worker.run...` expression in your code, but might make it a little more clear that the purpose of the expression is to take the current value of `worker` in the loop and pass it into the body of the lambda as a parameter.

Comment: It's probably important to point out that this behavior is not specific to lambda expressions, all functions work this way

Answer (score -1):

**Not an answer** but this works:

```py
t = list()
for i in [1,2,3,4]:
  func = lambda x=i: x*x
  t.append(func)

print(t[1]) 
# <function <lambda> at 0x7fdba6e6d790>
print(t[1]()) 
# 4
```

So you can bind your variables/parameters to a lambda function

It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452770/python-lambdas-binding-to-local-values)

Answer (score -2):

Think about it like this:

```py
def f(x):
    print(x)

f('yes')

>>> 'yes'

x = 'no'
def f(x=x):
    print(x)

f()
>>> 'no'

f('yes')
>>> 'yes'
```

Or in lambda world:

```py
f = lambda x:print(x)

f('yes')

>>> 'yes'

x = 'no'
f = lambda x=x: print(x)

f()
>>> 'no'

f('yes')
>>> 'yes'
```

So to make the answer WHY explicit for the commenters here, doing this lets each lambda be defined with a different default x value.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with lambda

Comment: the question is asking why it is used, the answer is easiest explained in terms for standard functions imo

Comment: This doesn't actually explain the purpose of why it's happening in the lambda though.

Comment: @Samwise how so?

Comment: See my answer for the explanation of why the parameter is being defined/passed this way in this situation.  :)

Comment: @Samwise I `thunk` your answer is a bit verbose

Comment: Your examples don't demonstrate at all the general, simple rule that answers the question: arguments take their value at run time, default parameters are evaluated at definition time.