# SyntaxError trying to return the value of assignment

Tags: python, syntax-error, assignment-operator

Suppose I have function with list parameter, and inside it's body I want to modify passed list, by this code:

```
spy = [0,0,7]

def replace_spy(lista):
    return lista[2]=lista[2]+1
```

but it show me the error : `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: See also: [Assignment inside lambda expression in Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282042/assignment-inside-lambda-expression-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assignment is a statement, not an expression. It has no value. So you can't `return` the value of an assignment.

Across languages that *do* allow this kind of thing, it's ambiguous what exactly the return value should be, but most of them—including C and the many languages derived from or inspired by C—would give you the new value of `lista[2]`<sup>1</sup>. So presumably you want this:

```
def replace_spy(lista):
    lista[2]=lista[2]+1
    return lista[2]
```

If you're looking to shorten things, this is fewer keystrokes, and probably more readable:

```
def replace_spy(lista):
    lista[2] += 1
    return lista[2]
```

---

<sub>1. As an "lvalue", but that isn't a meaningful thing in Python.</sub>

Comment: To shorten keystrokes even more, OP needs to get rid of the function entirely and just do `lista[2] += 1` :D

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Well, yeah, but let's assume this is a MCVE for a slightly less trivial function…