# How to pass a variable out of a lambda

Tags: python, function, lambda, playwright

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

url = "https://hls-js.netlify.app/demo/" 
with sync_playwright() as p: 

    browser = p.chromium.launch(channel = "chrome")
    page = browser.new_page() 
    page.on("response", lambda response: print(response.url) if (".m3u8" in response.url) else False) 
    page.goto(url) 
    page.wait_for_timeout(10*1000) 
    browser.close()
```

Hi guys, i need to pass the "response.url" inside a variable that I can use further in the code. I don't want response.url printed out, I just want to save that string in a variable. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282042/assignment-inside-lambda-expression-in-python

Comment: If you're on python 3.8 or above, this might work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14617232/6389787

Comment: function assigned to event can't return value - so you may have to assign result to global variable, or append to global list if you want to get many urls.

Comment: maybe better solution is to put rest of code inside this function and then you don't have to return value outside function.

Comment: @AshokArora it's not exactly the same, indeed those solutions do not fit with my code

Comment: @furas I tried to assign it to a global variable but it does not work out. The rest of the code needs to be outside unluckily

Comment: write normal function with `global url` and assing `url = response.url`. In `lambda` you can't use `global` and can't assing values to variables. You may only `append` to list.

Comment: @furas thanks it worked out

Answer (score 1):

Functions assigned to events (in any module) can't return value and you may need to use global variable for this. But `lambda` can't use `global` and can't assign value to variable so it needs normal function

```
url = ""

def on_response(response):
    global url  # inform functio to use external variable (instead of local variable) when you use `=` to assign value
    
    if ".m3u8" in response.url:
        url = response.url

page.on("response", on_response)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked out