# NiceGUI unable to make a variable global

Tags: python, nicegui

I am trying to use [NiceGUI](https://nicegui.io/) to create a website using NiceGUI's default text input code. This code works well, however, I need to globally expose the variable e.value however I failed to using a simple "=".

I attempted to set e.value as a variable using this code however it failed, giving me a syntax error.

Here is the code I used:

```py
from nicegui import ui
i = ("")
ui.input(label='Text', placeholder='start typing',
         on_change=lambda e: (e.value = (i))
         )
result = ui.label()

ui.run()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Variable binding was introduced in version 1.20 via dictionary binding.
Here's the documentation:
https://nicegui.io/documentation/bindings#bind_to_variable

```py
from nicegui import ui

i = ''
ui.input(label='Text', placeholder='start typing',
         on_change=lambda: ui.notify(f'{i = }')).bind_value_to(globals(), 'i')
    
ui.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is ([almost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14617232/3419103)) no way to make assignments in Python's lambda statements. But you can simply define a regular function to do that:

```py
i = ''

def handle_input(e):
    global i
    i = e.value

ui.input(label='Text', placeholder='start typing', on_change=handle_input)
```

---

**Update:** See @fam's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76194786/3419103) for how to do it with NiceGUI >=1.20

Comment: I tried using this however 'i' remained as empty even after entering a value

Comment: @user21406771 How do you know? How did you check the value of `i`?

Comment: I tried using ui.label to print I however it printed nothing, also when I hovered over it vs code said Literal = ''. This was with a value entered to the text box

Comment: @user21406771 If you have `label = ui.label(i)` somewhere in your code, the label won't automatically update when `i` changes. You need to update the text, e.g. with `label.text = e.value`, or use something like [bindings](https://nicegui.io/reference#bindings). (It seems like you're used to Streamlit. But this is not how Python usually works. See [here](https://github.com/zauberzeug/nicegui/discussions/21) in case my guess is right and you'd like to know more.)

Comment: It tried this method but I received a syntax error. I had never used Streamlit before, but after trying it, it seems to have the same issue

Comment: Ok, without seeing the code it's hard to give advice. Maybe we can continue the discussion on a Gist.

Comment: Here is the code:
from nicegui import ui
i =''
def handle_input(e):
    global i
    i = e.value
ui.input(label='Text', placeholder='start typing', on_change=handle_input)
ui.run()

Comment: @user21406771 Yes, that's the code from my answer. But you said "It tried this method". Show what you tried. And it's probably best to add the code to your question instead of squeezing it into the comments.